# Can a private member function of class A be declared as a friend of class B?

Tags: c++

Lippman's *Essential C++* section 4.7 does this. But I don't know why this code does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{   
void f();
//other members...
};

class B
{
//other members...
friend void A::f();
};

int main()
{
return 0;
}
```

While putting a "public:"before void f() in class A compiles. So Lippman is wrong?

p.s. Lippman's code is like this:

```
//...
class Triangular_iterator
{
//...
private:
void check_integrity() const;
//...
};

//...

class Triangular
{
//...
friend void Triangular_iterator::check_integrity();
//...
};

//...
```

Comment: Looks that way. Books are often wrong. http://ideone.com/uHTO0d

Comment: What is the actual error-message?

Comment: If this is on page 124, [the errata sheet](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0201485184/errata/errata.pdf) says it needs revision.

Comment: @bash.d 
a.cpp:6:7:error: ‘void A::f()’ is private
a.cpp:13:19: error: within this context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot declare the function or members of "class A" as friend of "class B" in "class B".
You must allow "class B" to be a friend of "class A"'s, and then make `A::f()` a friend of "class B"'s:

```
class A
{   
void f();

friend class B; //allow B access to private (protected) members and functions
};

class B
{
friend void A::f();
};
```

In real life, you can't determine to be someone's friend against their will, either!

See [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/friends.html) for an example.

Comment: Probably that the friendship is in the wrong direction compared to OP's example.

Comment: I don't know, this looks like a correct answer to me, if `B` needs to know about `A`'s private `void f()` member.

Comment: @juanchopanza It's not the wrong direction, since both directions are needed: `A` needs to make `B` a friend so that `B` can make `A::f` a friend.

Comment: Thank you, hvd, this is what I think, too. The class you declare `friend` in gives the declared class access to its members.

Comment: @hvd OP wants to access `B`'s non-public members from `A::f()`. Not to allow `B` to access all of `A`'s non-public members.

Comment: @juanchopanza But `B` cannot know about `A::f()` in order to grant access if `A::f()` is private and `B` is not a friend. I get what the question asks. But I don't think it's possible without making all of `B` a friend, like this answer says.

Comment: You certainly can declare a member function of another class to be a friend.

Comment: @bash.d But I want to allow A::f() to access to B's private members and you're allowing B to access A's. Moreover,　it seems possible to declare public members of A as friend of B.

Comment: @hvd right, so what OP wants cannot be done and it is a mistake in the book.

Comment: @jrok yes, you can, but there aren't any... `A` must give `B` access, but there aren't any other members to give access to, so it only leaves `friend class B` at this moment.

Comment: @juanchopanza What the OP asks for (not necessarily what the OP wants) is for a private member function to be a friend of another class. That *is* possible, like this answer says. It requires opening up more than should be needed, but it is possible to keep the member function private to other classes. It doesn't require making `f` public for everyone.

Comment: @bash.d You're misreading the Q. The intent is to grant `void A::f` friendship for B.

Answer (score 4):

A private member function of class A can be declared as a friend of class B. For this to work, class B must be declared a friend of class A (otherwise, class B cannot see the private member function of class A):

```
class A
{
    friend class B;
    void f();
};

class B
{
    friend void A::f();
};
```

In C++, the concept of *friend* comes from the fact that I allow the ones that I declare as friends to treat me differntly than non-friends. It does not involve treating the ones that I declare as friends differently than non-friends.

Comment: This just repeats bash.d's answer.

Comment: It doesn't. bash.d's answer states that you can't make a member function of another class be a friend, which isn't correct.

Comment: @hvd "A private member function of class A can be declared as a friend of class B. For this to work..."

Comment: @jrok No, that isn't what bash.d's answer states.

Comment: @hvd it is: "You cannot declare the function or members of "class A" as friend of "class B" in "class B"."

Comment: @juanchopanza Ah, now I see where you're coming from. Yes, that's incorrect. I'm fairly certain that's not what bash.d meant, and it's not how I read his answer, but I can see your point. The code in bash.d's answer is correct and (aside from ordering) identical to that in this answer.